# MySQL synchronisation between 2 db

Tags: linux, mysql

I am currently looking for a quick way to sync my production db and my dev-db.

I was thinking of doing it with something like this :

```
mysqladmin -u <user> -p<password> <dev-db_name> | mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> --databases <production-db-name> --add-drop-table
```

but it seems that it just prints all of the drump on the screen instead of piping it to the mysqladmin util. Would there be any suggestion to improve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are piping the output of `mysqladmin` into `mysqldump`.

Flip them around, also instead of `mysqladmin` use regular `mysql`, to that the command like looks something like this:

```
mysqldump ... | mysql ...
```

Comment: I just tried and got this error on the first table  
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `acces` at row: 1388 any idea ?

Comment: Hm. Try dumping into a file first, that is, without piping it straight to mysql client, do something like "mysqldump ... > script.sql" and see if that succeeds.

Comment: Seems to be the way to go. Thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the master / slave replication paradigm... if you just need to read from the dev-db, this is perfect...

Comment: Yup but problem is 
1- it's relatively complicated
2- cpanel
3- I need to only sync sometimes, not each night (in case I test db manipulations and I want to keep it the next day). But otherwise, great idea :)